# Querying names of a text document

Tags: text-processing

Print the lines that contain male ﬁrstnames in a file named muser.txt.

Print the ﬁrstnames of all males from Italy.

Print the number of diﬀerent ﬁrstnames of all males from Italy.

ex of doc:

```
Linda:F:Las Vegas, USA:18:telnet
Steve:M:Leipzig, Germany:33:ftp
Henry:M:Milan, Italy:19:sftp
Alice:F:Izmir, Turkey:32:pop3s
Robert:M:Verona, Italy:21:scp
Olga:F:Gorontalo, Indonesia:19:pop3s
Kimberly:F:Lille, France:25:ping
Henry:M:Oslo, Norway:26:ftp
Carol:F:New Delhi, India:23:pop3s
Thomas:M:New Delhi, India:32:http
```

Comment: What command you tried? It would be nice if you could let us know what commands you tried as well.

Comment: If you are asking people to do your homework for you, it is customary and polite to show your own attempts first...

Comment: I had single query attempts that didnt work at all,  I was totally lost, i didn't really understand that i could do multiple queries in a single line

Answer (score 2):

you can do this using `grep` and `cut` and (`awk` for duplicate users):

Print the lines that contain male ﬁrstnames in a ﬁle named muser.txt.

```
grep :M: YourFile > muser.txt
```

Print the ﬁrstnames of all males from Italy.

```
grep :M: YourFile | grep Italy: |cut -d: -f 1
```

Print the number of diﬀerent ﬁrstnames of all males from Italy.

```
grep :M: YourFile | grep Italy: |cut -d: -f 1| awk '!x[$0]++' | wc -l
```

`awk '!x[$0]++'` used to eliminate duplicate names.
`wc -l` to count the number of names(lines)

Comment: I am just curious, how can you print the first names of all males in the `grep` command?

Comment: @Ramesh, the first question is to print `the lines that contain` male ﬁrstnames in a ﬁle named muser.txt.

Comment: Why `-w` and not `-l`? `-w` counts words while `-l` counts lines. Granted, in this case you'll get the same result. A more serious issue is that you're not checking for field numbers. What if one of the names is `Bob Italy` for example?

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely what `awk` is designed for. It will split each line into fields according to the delimiter chosen. You can then refer to the first field as `$1`, the second as `$2` etc. The default field separator is whitespace but you can change that with `-F`.

1. Print the lines that contain male ﬁrstnames in a file named muser.txt.

   ```
   awk -F: '$2~/M/' file > muser.txt
   ```
2. Print the ﬁrstnames of all males from Italy.

   ```
   awk -F: '$2=="M" && $3~/Italy$/{print $1}' file
   ```
3. Print the number of different ﬁrstnames of all males from Italy.

   ```
   awk -F: '$2=="M" && $3~/Italy$/{print $1}' file | sort -u | wc -l
   ```

   or

   ```
   awk -F: '$2=="M" && $3~/Italy$/{!n[$1]++}END{print length(n)}' file
   ```